# Number at f(93) in fibonacci series has negative value, how?

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer, fibonacci

I am trying to printout fibonacci series upto 'N' numbers. All works as per expectation till f(92) but when I am trying to get the value of f(93), values turns out in negative: "-6246583658587674878". How this could be possible? What is the mistake in the logic below?

```
public long fibo(int x){
    long[] arr = new long[x+1];
    arr[0]=0;
    arr[1]=1;
    for (int i=2; i<=x; i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i-2]+arr[i-1];
    }
    return arr[x];
}

f(91) = 4660046610375530309
f(92) = 7540113804746346429    
f(93) = -6246583658587674878
```

Is this because of data type? What else data type I should use for printing fibonacci series upto N numbers? N could be any integer within range [0..10,000,000].

Comment: Seems to be integer overflow.  I'm willing to bet that `BigInteger` would be better to use.

Comment: Since long uses 64Bit for encoding the range is between [-2^63, 2^63 -1].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've encountered an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

```
 4660046610375530309 <-- term 91
+7540113804746346429 <-- term 92
====================
12200160415121876738 <-- term 93: the sum of the previous two terms
 9223372036854775808 <-- maximum value a long can store
```

To avoid this, use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which can deal with an arbitrary number of digits.
Here's your implementation converted to use `BigDecimal`:

```
public String fibo(int x){
    BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[x+1];
    arr[0]=BigInteger.ZERO;
    arr[1]=BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i=2; i<=x; i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i-2].add(arr[i-1]);
    }
    return arr[x].toString();u
}
```

Note that the return type must be String (or BigInteger) because even the modest value of 93 for `x` produces a result that is too great for any java primitive to represent.

Comment: I just came across this solution, and noticed that if x == 0 then arr[1]=BigInteger.ONE is going to throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Should probably have a check for that, and initialize the array accordingly: BigInteger[] arr; if (x == 0) { arr = new BigInteger[x+2]; } else { arr = new BigInteger[x+1]; }

Comment: @nih It would be better to throw an IllegalArgumentException if x < 1. What if x was -5?  The method accepts natural numbers from 1 (for the first Fibonacci number) to n (for the nth). This shows the essence of a working approach. It's not meant to be a bulletproof commercially useable solution.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I forget to step back and look at things in the context of being an example. And I sort of cheated on the negative numbers thing. I just set `x` to `Math.abs(x)` at the beginning. Lazy? Absolutely. But it avoids messing with exception handling for something so simple.

Answer (score 4):

This happened because the `long` type overflowed. In other words: the number calculated is too big to be represented as a `long`, and because of the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation used for integer types, after an overflow occurs the value becomes negative. To have a better idea of what's happening, look at this code:

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
=> 9223372036854775807  // maximum long value
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE + 1);
=> -9223372036854775808 // oops, the value overflowed!
```

The value of `fibo(93)` is `12200160415121876738`, which clearly is greater than the maximum value that fits in a `long`.

This is the way integers work in a computer program, after all they're limited and can not be infinite. A possible solution would be to use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to implement the method (instead of `long`), it's a class for representing arbitrary-precision integers in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly said in above answers, you've experienced overflow, however with below java 8 code snippet you can print series.

```
Stream.iterate(new BigInteger[] {BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE}, t -> new BigInteger[] {t[1], t[0].add(t[1])})
        .limit(100)
        .map(t -> t[0])
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```