# How can I write the total value at the beginning

Tags: c, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() { 
    int k; 
    unsigned long long int aray[94];  
    aray[0]=0; 
    aray[1]=1; 
    unsigned long long int total=0;
    printf("\n FIBONACCI  : \n\n");
    printf("1 + "); 
    for(k=2;k<=93;k++){ 
        aray[k]=aray[k-1]+aray[k-2]; 
        total+=aray[k];
        printf("%llu + ",aray[k]); 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Hi guys I need to print total value `printf("%llu",total);`at the begining but I don't know how to  do this thanks

Comment: It seems that `fib(93)` overflows even using 64 bits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667127/number-at-f93-in-fibonacci-series-has-negative-value-how

Comment: At the beginning of what? The loop? The `main` function?

Comment: @davidranieri no if u use unsgined long long int it can write 93th but after it is broken i need just how to write at the  begining  total value

Comment: @forcebru After running the code, 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 per part, that is, total value = 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5

Comment: You want `printf("%llu",total);`?

Comment: i want to  do this === total value = 1 + 1 + 2 +3 + 5 like this

Comment: Where is that code coming from? Did you write this?

Comment: I write this  but i can just print total value end of the 1+1+2+3+5+8..... = total value , i want to write begining at that

Comment: So you want to print something that is not yet calculated? Then you need to run the loop twice, one to calculate the total and the other to show each sequence

Comment: @davidranieri woewwww that is true you are smart thanks bro i got this

Comment: `1+1+2+3+5+8..... = total` here total is not at the beginning, do you mean at the end? In this case use `printf("%llu",total);` after the `for` block

Comment: @davidranieri yeah i know i could do this but now i learn how to write at begining thank u

Comment: @ÖmerSertkaya LOL you are driving me crazy!

Comment: @davidranieri i love buddy

Comment: If you want to print the value of fib(93) **before actually calculating it in your code**, you'll have to use a calculator and then do printf("12200160415121876738"). This will of course always only print the value of fib(93), so if you need more flexibility you could alternatively try to implement a time machine (but that might be quite complicated)

Answer (score 0):

calculate and "print" into **a large enough** string (or `realloc()` as needed)

```
    char bigenough[200000];
    char *p = bigenough;
    loop {
        /* ... calculate ... */
        p += sprintf(p, "%llu + ", value);
    }
```

afterwards print total and result string

```
    printf("total: %llu = ", total);
    printf("%s\n", bigenough);
```